# Jinja2: Object of type Namespace is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, jinja2

To send my backend data to my frontend/javascript in my Jinja2 view i'm using something like :

```
{% for organization in team.organizations %}
  {{ teamOrganizations.append(organization.namespace) or "" }}
{% endfor %}

<div data-json='{{ teamOrganizations|tojson }}'></div>
```

But with a namespace, I have the following error : `Object of type Namespace is not JSON serializable`

If I do a {{ organization.namespace }} I have the expected value displayed as string, why this is not JSON serializable ?

Thx

EDIT: I fixed it with `teamOrganizations.append("" ~ organization.namespace)`

Comment: What are you trying to do here? and why are you doing logic in templates?

Comment: I'm building a json for my vuejs component

Comment: Did you want to pass `team.organizations` through a filter then use the for loop?

Comment: would it not be better to build the json on the server and post it as it is needed rather than creating it in the template? or is there a reason youre doing it that way?

Comment: @Craicerjack it's to re-use the current data pushed to the view and avoid to have to duplicate this data

Comment: Glad you fixed it, you could also use jinja's map https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map